# How to integrate 2 compoonent spline function

Tags: numerical-integration, splines

I have a Spline function defined as follows.

```
Points = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}};

bsf = BSplineFunction[Points, SplineDegree -> 1];
```

A Parametric Plot look like this:

```
ParametricPlot[bsf[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

But when I try to do NIntegrate, I get for the first component

```
NIntegrate[bsf[t][[1]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

An output of 0.5 as it should be, but for the second component

```
NIntegrate[bsf[t][[2]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

I get as an output

[image]

I still get the correct output though. But If I just type

```
NIntegrate[bsf[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

I just get error

[image]

[image]

Why is this and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look at `InputForm[bsf]` to see what you are extracting with your part specifications. I don't think you are getting what you intend. Also, I think we are running in circles here because you haven't disclosed your true goal. From your previous question, *for what purpose* do you want a parametric representation of those lines? If you are trying to get the area enclosed by some points there are other more direct ways. Please explain your underlying problem (perhaps in a new question) and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Define a new function that only accepts numerical arguments: `gg[t_?NumericQ, index_] := bsf[t][[index]]`.  Then you can feed this to `NIntegrate`, e.g. `NIntegrate[gg[t, 2], {t, 0, 1}]` yields `0.5`.  The issue is that `bsf[t]` doesn't evaluate to a list of two elements until *after* you have entered a numerical value for `t`.  I haven't figured out yet if there's a way to extract the two component functions.

Answer (score 5):

`Indexed`.

```
NIntegrate[Indexed[bsf[t], 1], {t, 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[Indexed[bsf[t], 2], {t, 0, 1}]
```

> `0.5`.

> `0.5`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options I could come up with here.  The first is to define your `bsf` function to only accept numerical inputs. That is,

```
Points = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}};
bsf = BSplineFunction[Points, SplineDegree -> 1];
bsfNum[t_?NumericQ, index_] := bsf[t][[index]]
```

Then,

```
NIntegrate[gg[t, 1], {t, 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[gg[t, 2], {t, 0, 1}]
(* 0.5 *)
(* 0.5 *)
```

The issue is that `bsf[t]` doesn't evaluate to a list of two elements until after you have entered a numerical value for `t`, and this forces *Mathematica* to define a numerical function instead.

Alternatively, we can construct the B-spline functions from the `BSplineBasis` functions, using the knots generated internally by `BSplineFunction`.  We define,

```
bsfKnot[t_] = Sum[
   Points[[j + 1]] BSplineBasis[{1, Rationalize@First@bsf["Knots"]}, j, t],
   {j, 0, Length@Points - 1}
  ];
```

Then, this seems to be the right function:

```
ParametricPlot[bsfKnot[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

In addition, we can use `Integrate` or `NIntegrate`:

```
Integrate[bsfKnot[t][[2]], {t, 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[bsfKnot[t][[2]], {t, 0, 1}]
(* 1/2 *)
(* 0.5 *)
```